# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in twilio with angular

Tags: twilio

```js
private async getAuthToken(name: string, room: string) {
    const auth = await this.http
    .post('http://localhost:8000/token', {name, room}).toPromise();
    return auth;
  }

  async onRoom(){
    const token = await this.getAuthToken(this.user, this.room);
    try {
      await connect(
          token, {
              name,
          }).then(room =>
            {
              this.activeRoom = room;
              console.log(this.activeRoom);
              
              console.log(`Successfully joined a Room: ${room}`);
              // Log new Participants as they connect to the Room
              room.once('participantConnected', participant => {
                console.log(`El participante "${participant.identity}" se está conectando`);
              });

              // Log Participants as they disconnect from the Room
              room.once('participantDisconnected', participant => {
                console.log(`El participante "${participant.identity}"se está desconectando`);
              });
              room.on('participantConnected', participant => {
                console.log(`El participante ${participant.identity} se conecto`);
                console.log(participant.track)
                participant.track.forEach(track => {
                  console.log('foreach participant');
                  const localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('remote-media');
                  localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
                });
                participant.on('trackAdded', track => {
                  console.log('track added');
                  const localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('remote-media');
                  localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
                })
              });
              room.on('participantDisconnected', participant => {
                console.log(`El participante ${participant.identity} se desconecto` );
              });
              room.on('disconnected', room => {
                room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(track => {
                  const attachedElements = track.detach();
                  attachedElements.forEach(element => element.remove());
                  console.log(`La sala ${room} se ha desconectado con éxito`)
                });
              });
            });
    } catch (error) {
        return console.error(`Unable to connect to Room: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
```

I manage to connect rooms, but when another user enters the room I throw the following error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

And also when I want to leave the room I throw the following error

ERROR TypeError: track.detach is not a function

Comment: Which version of Twilio Video JS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The first call is to participant.track  and the second is participant.tracks  .  Which one is correct ?  The forEach error implies that participant.track does not exist.